# When I build Xamarin solution I see: "javac.exe" exited with code 2 error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I just created a new Xamarin solution in visual studio. Here is how the solution looks like:

[image]

And when I try to build, it shows the following error:

> "javac.exe" exited with code 2.

Here is the error logs in output window:

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: App2.Droid, Configuration:
>   Debug Any CPU ------ 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(605,2):
>   warning : Failed to get the Java SDK version. Found java version
>   "9.0.1" 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(605,2):
>   warning : Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(605,2):
>   warning : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed
>   mode) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(605,2):
>   warning :  but this does not seem to contain a valid version number.
>   1>  App2.Droid -> C:\Users\abaig\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\App2\App2\App2.Droid\bin\Debug\App2.Droid.dll
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1914,3):
>   error MSB6006: "javac.exe" exited with code 2.
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Any Idea what could be wrong?

Comment: This seems to describe exit code 2: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95562/java-exit-code-2-too-many-references-multidex-not-fix-the-problem

Answer (score 2):

try to enable your multidex, go to yourandroidproject > rightclick > properties > Android options and click enable Multi-Dex

Answer (score 1):

Here is what solved this problem.

While setting up Xamarin I had installed [Java SE Development Kit 9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html). Now I've uninstalled it and instead I have installed [Java SE Development Kit 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). After installing Java SE Development Kit 8, all I did is, update the JDK location in Android Settings, so that it now points to JDK v8. See below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac with java sdk jdk-9.0.1.jdk installed using visual studio I got this build error:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error MSB6006: "javac" exited with code 2. (MSB6006) (ProjectX.Droid)

I installed java sdk jdk1.8.0_151.jdk (did not un-installed jdk 9) and changed java sdk (jdk) Location (preferences > sdk location > andriod > locations) to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home

...then I have no build errors

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks. Note to others: we're changing the "Java SDK (JDK) Location" setting, not the "Android SDK Location" setting with this solution.